# Angular 2 (v.2.4.0) and IE9

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-9

i am trying to make an angular 2 app work with IE9 but no polyfill seems to do the job. Specifically, i am using angular-cli, and my polyfills.ts file includes all those files that are stated in angular documentation. However, when i am running the app in IE9, i get the following error:

[IE9 console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTTx4.png)

Comment: something wrong with your polyfils? have you checked the error line?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get it to work with IE9 try the following pollyfills:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

check these links too

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-ie9-shims
```

but according to angular page angular does support IE9 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html